# Scraping a table for data

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I need some help to download the stock table located in this [URL](https://es.investing.com/stock-screener/?sp=country::5%7Csector::a%7Cindustry::a%7CequityType::a%7Cexchange::a%7Ceq_market_cap::110630000,1990000000000%3Ceq_market_cap;1):

I’ve tried with the code below to at least grab the first line, but what in the inspector is showed as :

```
<a target=”_blank”href=”/equities/apple-computer-inc” title=Apple Inc”>Apple</a>
```

I can only see:

`A title={fullName} href="about:{pairLink}" target=_blank>{pairName}`

This is the code I've put together:

```
 Sub table()
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Dim Tables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim table As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim TableRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    
    XMLReq.Open "GET", "https://es.investing.com/stock-screener/?sp=country::5|sector::a|industry::a|equityType::a|exchange::a|eq_market_cap::110630000,1990000000000%3Ceq_market_cap;2", False
    XMLReq.send
    
    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & "- " & XMLReq.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    Set Tables = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("Table")
    
    For Each table In Tables

        If table.className = "displayNone genTbl openTbl resultsStockScreenerTbl elpTbl " Then
            For Each TableRow In table.getElementsByTagName("td")
                Debug.Print TableRow.innerHTML
            Next
        End If
    
    Next table
    
End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Likely a dynamic webpage where the content you want comes from a different url via an xhr request the current page makes to update content. Generally these are viewable via dev tools in the browser or with network monitoring tools e.g.wireshark. As dynamic content won't be present in the initial request you are making. You can test this by switching off javascript in the browser and re-loading the content. If dynamic the content you want won't be there and you will get something similar to what you are seeing with your code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the actual data that fills the table is pulled from JSON from another request that some javascript or something runs on the page.
This might make it easier to parse the response with a json parser but it might be difficult to compose the correct request to get the data you want. The owners of the website might not want you do do this so they might not make it easy.
[image]

It looks like a POST request with a bunch of parameters and also a cookie sent along. So basically you would need to re-create this POST request by adding all of the correct parameters and the correct cookie in the header. I would get a web debugging program like fiddler (shown above) to look and see what is going on.

I was going to also suggest you check and see if that website provides an API but it looks [like it doesn't?](https://www.investing-support.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005473825-Do-you-provide-an-API-)

EDIT:
I was actually able to get the JSON with the data you want by pretty much just copying the request used on the site:

```
 Sub getdata()
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    
    XMLReq.Open "POST", "https://es.investing.com/stock-screener/Service/SearchStocks", False
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    XMLReq.setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
    
    XMLReq.send "country%5B%5D=5&exchange%5B%5D=95&exchange%5B%5D=2&exchange%5B%5D=1&sector=5%2C12%2C3%2C8%2C9%2C1%2C7%2C6%2C2%2C11%2C4%2C10&industry=74%2C56%2C73%2C29%2C25%2C4%2C47%2C12%2C8%2C44%2C52%2C45%2C71%2C99%2C65%2C70%2C98%2C40%2C39%2C42%2C92%2C101%2C6%2C30%2C59%2C77%2C100%2C9%2C50%2C46%2C88%2C94%2C62%2C75%2C14%2C51%2C93%2C96%2C34%2C55%2C57%2C76%2C66%2C5%2C3%2C41%2C87%2C67%2C85%2C16%2C90%2C53%2C32%2C27%2C48%2C24%2C20%2C54%2C33%2C19%2C95%2C18%2C22%2C60%2C17%2C11%2C35%2C31%2C43%2C97%2C81%2C69%2C102%2C72%2C36%2C78%2C10%2C86%2C7%2C21%2C2%2C13%2C84%2C1%2C23%2C79%2C58%2C49%2C38%2C89%2C63%2C64%2C80%2C37%2C28%2C82%2C91%2C61%2C26%2C15%2C83%2C68&equityType=ORD%2CDRC%2CPreferred%2CUnit%2CClosedEnd%2CREIT%2CELKS%2COpenEnd%2CRight%2CParticipationShare%2CCapitalSecurity%2CPerpetualCapitalSecurity%2CGuaranteeCertificate%2CIGC%2CWarrant%2CSeniorNote%2CDebenture%2CETF%2CADR%2CETC%2CETN&eq_market_cap%5Bmin%5D=110630000&eq_market_cap%5Bmax%5D=1990000000000&pn=1&order%5Bcol%5D=eq_market_cap&order%5Bdir%5D=d"
    
    If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        MsgBox "problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & "- " & XMLReq.statusText
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Debug.Print XMLReq.responseText
    
End Sub
```

So now you will just need to figure out how to parse the JSON response.

Comment: Hi @garbb, it works perfectly fine! Thanks a lot. Indeed the developers of this page have done the impossible to ruin may day. The JSON format they use are not parsed correctly with the JSonConverte I normally use (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON ).